# How to include stylesheets in twig

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twig

How do I include stylesheets in twig? The documentation only refers to symfony2.

I want to benefit from twig caching system and to be afle to use my vars in stylesheets.

I'm not using symfony2, just plain and simple twig library.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think Twig is designed for this. You could include your css between `<style>` tags however. Then you can use your twig variables.

Answer (score 0):

same as you would normally with `<link>` tag.
twig is a template engine for PHP i.e has shortcuts for common structures(loops, if condition etc) of PHP with other features check out http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: So it can't cache stylesheets?

I can't pass variables using <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> the stylesheet is send to the user directly.

Comment: how do you plan to use it. can u give example